# How to detect an empty Dictionary without crashing in Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift2, nsdictionary

I am trying to detect if the dictionary coming from API is empty or has values but whenever i am trying to do Dict.count it crashes.

```
if let personalInfo = self.scanResult?.fields { // personalInfo has 0 values but not nil

let image = NSData(base64EncodedString: (personalInfo["Photo"] as? String)!, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0)) // Crashes
}
```

I also tried isEmpty and it crashes there as well.

Comment: I'm not great at Swift, but it looks like you're trying to make an image with 0 data in it - why?  I think that making an image with only "0" as its data would be both useless and by definition bound to crash... am I missing something?

Comment: first you should check whether your Dic obj is nil or not, if it is not nil you can call count method with this

Answer (score 0):

You should unwrap personalInfo["Photo"] before trying to use it. This way you can ensure you're not trying to instantiate NSData without a value for the Photo key being present

```
if let personalInfo = self.scanResult?.fields{
    if let encodedString = personalInfo["Photo"] as? String{
        let image = NSData(base64EncodedString: encodedString,options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue:0))
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to go that far and just stop when i see the number of values in the dictionary is 0. How should i do that ?

Comment: What type is self.scanResult?.fields ? If it is truly a swift dictionary, then you could check the count by the method, personalInfo.count

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to check dictionary keys count is greater than 0. For example:

```
let dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = Dictionary()
if dictionary.keys.count > 0  {
   // This mean dictionary has values.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "count" of dictionary. See the code.

```
     if let personalInfo = self.scanResult?.fields {
            if personalInfo.count > 0  {
                if let base64ImageString = personalInfo["Photo"] as? String {
                    if let image = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64ImageString, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0)) {
                        // do your stuff with image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the self.scanResult.fields was coming out as NSNull. so i found these 3 methods which resolves the problem.

```
func isNotNull(object:AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        guard let object = object else {
            return false
        }
        return (isNotNSNull(object) && isNotStringNull(object))
    }

    func isNotNSNull(object:AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return object.classForCoder != NSNull.classForCoder()
    }

    func isNotStringNull(object:AnyObject) -> Bool {
        if let object = object as? String where object.uppercaseString == "NULL" {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

And i just call like this :

```
if self.isNotNSNull((self.scanResult?.fields)!
{

}
```